Why does go require a file to specify a package?
I'm still learning go and packages confused me a lot at first.
It seems like the package name has to match the directory name,
except for 'main' which is in the root directory of a module?
If I try to give the package of a file any other name, it won't build.
I think it confused me because of that.
Is there a reason for this?  Is it a sort of verification that
you know what you're doing and didn't move a file by accident?
Is there some other name you could use for the package that
won't cause an error when building?
EDIT
Ah, I see...   You don't have to use the directory name, but it only throws an error if you mix .go files with different package names in the same directory:
When I try to use a different package name (i.e. notdir), go gives me an error:

cmd\root.go:14:2: found packages day05 (day05.go) and notdir (sample.go) in C:\git\go\go-advent-of-code-2024\cmd\day05

And normally the package name comes from the last part of the path, but you can specify it if they don't match:
hello "github.com/JasonGoemaat/go-advent-of-code-2024/cmd/testf"
goodbye "github.com/JasonGoemaat/go-advent-of-code-2024/cmd/testf/testg"


The package name does not have to match the directory name, that’s only common by convention. There are lots of packages which don’t match. (You can also have a second _test package name for black box tests)

Ah, thanks.  Guess I misunderstood the error messages or didn't pay enough attention and have the desire to put in the effort to test some other things out.  Looks like you can use a package name that doesn't match the directory name, but you can't mix package names in the same directory.   And technically the alias isn't required, but go fmt which runs automatically when I save adds it if the names are different.

And now I guess there is at least one exception to that 'rule', looking up things I see that it is recommended (though not necessary apparently since I haven't been doing it) to use XXX_test fo the package name for tests in the same directory, though that prevents you from testing private functions.

I wouldn't say _test packages are recommended, it's just a way of writing black-box tests within the same directory; you don't see it used too often.
